# Wait until program starts

Tags: cmd, vbscript

I was wondering if there is any better way to wait until program starts before interacting with it?
Right now I'm using `sleep` which isn't exactly great.
Just to be clear I don't want to wait until program is finished (terminated) just to wait until it starts to be able to interact with it.

my code:

```
set MyShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
MyShell.Run "<path to my exe app>"
WScript.Sleep 4000
MyShell.AppActivate "<my app name>"
MyShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
...
```

Comment: `SendKeys` is a terrible, unreliable way of automation and should only be used after everything (and I mean *everything*) else has failed. And maybe not even then. Please explain what program you're trying to automate (and in what way) and we may be able to suggest better approaches to the problem.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thank for your response! Actually `SendKeys` was just an example. The point is that I need to wait a few seconds until program starts and data in it refreshes ( it's a token generator).

Comment: Does the program do anything to indicate that it is fully initialized such as creating or deleting a file? Do you have control/source code for the program in question?

Comment: I do not have source code for the program. All the program does is generating new token code.

Comment: In Windows you call `WaitForInputIdle`. But VBScript can't call this. Try stating your problem rather than asking why your solution doesn't work.

Comment: I Think it is better To Use Again `WSH.Sleep 4000`